# Show that $\mathbb{P}(|\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i-\frac{1}{2}|>\frac{1}{2})\leq\frac{1}{3n}$

Tags: probability, uniform-distribution

Suppose $X_1, X_2, ..., X_n$ are independent uniformly distributed random variables on [0,1].

Show that $\mathbb{P}(|\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i-\frac{1}{2}|>\frac{1}{2})\leq\frac{1}{3n}$

I've started rewriting this equation
\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}(|\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i-\frac{1}{2}|>\frac{1}{2}) & = \mathbb{P}(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i-\frac{1}{2}>\frac{1}{2}) + \mathbb{P}(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i-\frac{1}{2}<-\frac{1}{2})\\
&=\mathbb{P}(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i>1) + \mathbb{P}(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i<0)
\end{align}
How can I go continue from here? Or is this not the way to go?

Comment: $$\left[\left|\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i-\frac{1}{2}\right|>\frac{1}{2}\right]={}{}{}{}\varnothing$$

Comment: @Did Why is this so?

Comment: @Whizkid95 the last expression you got has two terms, the first says the average of values which are less than 1 is bigger than one, the other is the probability that the average of non negative number is less than zero

Comment: @clark But in the problem I'm trying to solve, where does the value $\frac{1}{3n}$ come from?

Comment: the probability of the empty set is zero the value $\frac{1}{3n}$ is there to make the problem harder, that is not to point the solver to the right direction

Comment: @clark I've posted the answer. So the $\frac{1}{3n}$ wasn't just to make the problem harder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use Chebyshev's inequality on the random variable $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i$, which states the following:
$$\mathbb{P}(|Y-\mathbb{E}(Y)|\geq a)\leq\frac{1}{a^2}
 \text{Var}(Y)$$ Thus
$$\mathbb{P}(|\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i-\frac{1}{2}|>\frac{1}{2})\leq4 \text{Var}\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i\right)=\frac{4}{n^2}n\cdot\frac{1}{12}=\frac{1}{3n}$$